# String compression in C with esp idf and miniz

Tags: c, compression, esp32, esp-idf

I would appreciate any help. I want to (un)compress a string with the defalte algorithm on a esp32.

I have this main.c and when i try to "idf build" it includes the "miniz.h" correctly but it can't find the functions that are in the header file. I can't find anything in the esp-idf docs. And don't know what is missing. I am pretty new to the esp-idf framework so i could just be missing something.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>  // for strlen
#include <assert.h>
#include "miniz.h"

void app_main() {

    // original string len = 36
    char a[50] = "Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello!";
    // placeholder for the compressed (deflated) version of "a" 
    char b[50];
    // placeholder for the UNcompressed (inflated) version of "b"
    char c[50];

    printf("Uncompressed size is: %u\n", strlen(a));
    printf("Uncompressed string is: %s\n", a);

    printf("\n----------\n\n");
    // STEP 1.
    // deflate a into b. (that is, compress a into b)
    // zlib struct
    mz_stream defstream;
    defstream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    defstream.zfree = Z_NULL;
    defstream.opaque = Z_NULL;
    // setup "a" as the input and "b" as the compressed output
    defstream.avail_in = (uInt)strlen(a)+1; // size of input, string + terminator
    defstream.next_in = (Bytef *)a; // input char array
    defstream.avail_out = (uInt)sizeof(b); // size of output
    defstream.next_out = (Bytef *)b; // output char array
    // the actual compression work.
    mz_deflateInit(&defstream, Z_BEST_COMPRESSION);
    mz_deflate(&defstream, Z_FINISH);
    mz_deflateEnd(&defstream);
    // This is one way of getting the size of the output
    printf("Compressed size is: %lu\n", strlen(b));
    printf("Compressed string is: %s\n", b);
    printf("\n----------\n\n");
    // STEP 2.
    // inflate b into c
    // zlib struct
    mz_stream infstream;
    infstream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    infstream.zfree = Z_NULL;
    infstream.opaque = Z_NULL;
    // setup "b" as the input and "c" as the compressed output
    infstream.avail_in = (uInt)((char*)defstream.next_out - b); // size of input
    infstream.next_in = (Bytef *)b; // input char array
    infstream.avail_out = (uInt)sizeof(c); // size of output
    infstream.next_out = (Bytef *)c; // output char array
    // the actual DE-compression work.
    mz_inflateInit(&infstream);
    mz_inflate(&infstream, MZ_NO_FLUSH);
    mz_inflateEnd(&infstream);
    printf("Uncompressed size is: %zu\n", strlen(c));
    printf("Uncompressed string is: %s\n", c);
    // make sure uncompressed is exactly equal to original.
    assert(strcmp(a,c)==0);
}
```

log of `ìdf.py build`:

```
/config/esp/test/main/main.c: In function 'app_main':
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:24:5: error: unknown type name 'mz_stream'
   24 |     mz_stream defstream;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:25:14: error: request for member 'zalloc' in something not a structure or union
   25 |     defstream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
      |              ^
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:25:24: error: 'Z_NULL' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'NULL'?
   25 |     defstream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
      |                        ^~~~~~
      |                        NULL
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:25:24: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:26:14: error: request for member 'zfree' in something not a structure or union
   26 |     defstream.zfree = Z_NULL;
      |              ^
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:27:14: error: request for member 'opaque' in something not a structure or union
   27 |     defstream.opaque = Z_NULL;
      |              ^
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:29:14: error: request for member 'avail_in' in something not a structure or union
   29 |     defstream.avail_in = (uInt)strlen(a)+1; // size of input, string + terminator
      |              ^
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:29:27: error: 'uInt' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'uint'?
   29 |     defstream.avail_in = (uInt)strlen(a)+1; // size of input, string + terminator
      |                           ^~~~
      |                           uint
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:29:32: error: expected ';' before 'strlen'
   29 |     defstream.avail_in = (uInt)strlen(a)+1; // size of input, string + terminator
      |                                ^~~~~~
      |                                ;
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:30:14: error: request for member 'next_in' in something not a structure or union
   30 |     defstream.next_in = (Bytef *)a; // input char array
      |              ^
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:30:26: error: 'Bytef' undeclared (first use in this function)
   30 |     defstream.next_in = (Bytef *)a; // input char array
      |                          ^~~~~
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:30:33: error: expected expression before ')' token
   30 |     defstream.next_in = (Bytef *)a; // input char array
      |                                 ^
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:31:14: error: request for member 'avail_out' in something not a structure or union
   31 |     defstream.avail_out = (uInt)sizeof(b); // size of output
      |              ^
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:31:33: error: expected ';' before 'sizeof'
   31 |     defstream.avail_out = (uInt)sizeof(b); // size of output
      |                                 ^~~~~~
      |                                 ;
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:32:14: error: request for member 'next_out' in something not a structure or union
   32 |     defstream.next_out = (Bytef *)b; // output char array
      |              ^
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:32:34: error: expected expression before ')' token
   32 |     defstream.next_out = (Bytef *)b; // output char array
      |                                  ^
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:34:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'mz_deflateInit' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   34 |     mz_deflateInit(&defstream, MZ_BEST_COMPRESSION);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:34:32: error: 'MZ_BEST_COMPRESSION' undeclared (first use in this function)
   34 |     mz_deflateInit(&defstream, MZ_BEST_COMPRESSION);
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:35:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'mz_deflate' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   35 |     mz_deflate(&defstream, MZ_FINISH);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:35:28: error: 'MZ_FINISH' undeclared (first use in this function)
   35 |     mz_deflate(&defstream, MZ_FINISH);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:36:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'mz_deflateEnd' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   36 |     mz_deflateEnd(&defstream);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:38:50: error: request for member 'total_out' in something not a structure or union
   38 |     printf("Compressed size is: %lu\n, defstream.total_out);
      |                                                  ^
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:44:5: error: unknown type name 'mz_stream'
   44 |     mz_stream infstream;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:45:14: error: request for member 'zalloc' in something not a structure or union
   45 |     infstream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
      |              ^
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:46:14: error: request for member 'zfree' in something not a structure or union
   46 |     infstream.zfree = Z_NULL;
      |              ^
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:47:14: error: request for member 'opaque' in something not a structure or union
   47 |     infstream.opaque = Z_NULL;
      |              ^
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:49:14: error: request for member 'avail_in' in something not a structure or union
   49 |     infstream.avail_in = (uInt)((char*)defstream.next_out - b); // size of input
      |              ^
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:49:49: error: request for member 'next_out' in something not a structure or union
   49 |     infstream.avail_in = (uInt)((char*)defstream.next_out - b); // size of input
      |                                                 ^
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:50:14: error: request for member 'next_in' in something not a structure or union
   50 |     infstream.next_in = (Bytef *)b; // input char array
      |              ^
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:50:33: error: expected expression before ')' token
   50 |     infstream.next_in = (Bytef *)b; // input char array
      |                                 ^
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:51:14: error: request for member 'avail_out' in something not a structure or union
   51 |     infstream.avail_out = (uInt)sizeof(c); // size of output
      |              ^
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:51:33: error: expected ';' before 'sizeof'
   51 |     infstream.avail_out = (uInt)sizeof(c); // size of output
      |                                 ^~~~~~
      |                                 ;
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:52:14: error: request for member 'next_out' in something not a structure or union
   52 |     infstream.next_out = (Bytef *)c; // output char array
      |              ^
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:52:34: error: expected expression before ')' token
   52 |     infstream.next_out = (Bytef *)c; // output char array
      |                                  ^
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:54:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'mz_inflateInit' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   54 |     mz_inflateInit(&infstream);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:55:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'mz_inflate' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   55 |     mz_inflate(&infstream, MZ_NO_FLUSH);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:55:28: error: 'MZ_NO_FLUSH' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'TDEFL_NO_FLUSH'?
   55 |     mz_inflate(&infstream, MZ_NO_FLUSH);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                            TDEFL_NO_FLUSH
/config/esp/test/main/main.c:56:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'mz_inflateEnd' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   56 |     mz_inflateEnd(&infstream);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: What are the errors you're seeing? I assume they are undefined reference errors. There's probably a library you need to link with or one or more c files you need to include in your build.

Comment: Yes I get many "undeclared" and "implicit declaration of function" during build

Comment: The miniz.h file is in the esp-idf repo under: [/espressif/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/include/esp32/rom/miniz.h](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/components/esp_rom/include/esp32/rom/miniz.h)

Comment: Could you also describe how you doing the build? Are you using the build commands from the IDF project? I assume it needs to link correctly to the source code from the ESP-IDF project and embed it into the chip, along with your app code. Adding a header file is not enough for the linker.

Comment: I run ```idf.py build```. But where is the source code for miniz in the esp-idf repo?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you're trying to use the API of zlib, not miniz. Here's the API for miniz: https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/components/esp_rom/include/miniz.h

The implementation appears to be in the ROM of the chip.

Comment: Should I include it via "rom/miniz.h" ?

Comment: No, considering that this file says `#warning "{target}/rom/miniz.h is deprecated, please use (#include "miniz.h") instead"`

Comment: And that is what i am using```#include "miniz.h"```

Comment: Yes, but have a look inside `miniz.h` - it has no struct named `z_stream` or function named `inflateInit()`. Your code needs to use the stuff defined there, e.g. `mz_stream` and `mz_inflateInit()`. Or, alternatively disable preprocessor constant `MINIZ_NO_ZLIB_COMPATIBLE_NAMES`

Comment: Tried that, and you are right, but still failing. sadly

Comment: Perhaps you could add the exact error output to your post